# Raspberry Pi Python Press button and run some code

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm a total noob with Raspberry Pi and Python, and I'm trying to make a simple traffic light simulator with 5 LEDs and a button. Here's my code:

while True:

```
inputValue = GPIO.input(17)
if (inputValue == False): #if the button was pushed
    print("Button press ")
else: #if it wasn't pressed 
    GPIO.output(green_traf_LED, GPIO.LOW) #green T. LED on
    GPIO.output(red_walk_LED, GPIO.LOW) #red W. LED always on
    time.sleep(6)
    GPIO.output(green_traf_LED, GPIO.HIGH) #green T. LED off
    #yellow blinking, red
    for k in range(10):
        #red walk LED still on
        GPIO.output(yellow_traf_LED, GPIO.LOW) #yellow T. LED on
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(yellow_traf_LED, GPIO.HIGH) #yellow T. LED off
        time.sleep(0.2)
    #red, white
    GPIO.output(red_traf_LED, GPIO.LOW) #red T. LED ON
    time.sleep(6)
    GPIO.output(red_traf_LED, GPIO.HIGH) #red T. LED off
time.sleep(0.3)
```

So basically, when the button isn't pushed, I want my python code to run code x. When the button is pushed, I want it to run code y and afterward, continue running code x until I press it again. But when I run the code, none of the LEDs light up, and when i press the button, the message doesn't appear. I'm 100% certain that the wiring, LED numbering, and button numbering is correct, so what do I need to fix?

Comment: Do you get the right value when your button is pressed?

Comment: I think the problem is that your code is just checking once for button_click then during the whole led on and off process your code isn't looking anymore for input events.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you seem to have inverted `HIGH` and `LOW`.

You need a service/background script to listen to the input port and put the state in a file for example. If installed, Node-RED can monitor GPIO ports so you won't need to program a service.

[Source](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/)

```
import time
#initialise a previous input variable to 0 (assume button not pressed last)
prev_input = 0
while True:
    #take a reading
    input = GPIO.input(17)
    #if the last reading was low and this one high, print
    if ((not prev_input) and input):
        print("Button pressed") #put information in file or other...
        #update previous input
        prev_input = input
        #slight pause to debounce
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

Then in your above program instead of reading the pin value, read the file contents.